# from ArrayList into JComboBox

Tags: java, arraylist, jcombobox

I have an assignment set, I need to populate a JComboBox from Games entered into an ArrayList, right now I have it all setup, except for the whole adding to the arraylist, I just want to get the input working. It loads in, but it prints the array address, not the string, is there any way of getting around this? My code is below. Please note, this isn't the whole thing, this is the file that is causing me troubles, my other files are used for displaying the files.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GameCombo extends JPanel {
  ArrayList<Game> gamesList = new ArrayList<Game>();

  //String[] games = {"", "[Halo: Reach] Xbox 360; Action; $108.00; 2;", "[Dead Space] Xbox 360; Horror; $65.00; 1;"}; 

    public GameCombo() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,1,1));
    gamesList.add(new Game());
    gamesList.add(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
    gamesList.add(new Game("[Dead Space]", 3, 2, 80.00, 1));

    JComboBox _gameBox = new JComboBox(getGames());
        add(_gameBox);
    }

    public Object[] getGames() {
        return gamesList.toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AKJ was right.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComboTest extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<Game> gamesList = new ArrayList<Game>();

    private class Game {
        private String title = "";

        public Game() {}

        public Game(String title, int x, int y, double z, int a) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        /********************************************************/
        /********************************************************/
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.title;
        }
        /********************************************************/
        /********************************************************/
    }

    public ComboTest() {
        gamesList.add(new Game());
        gamesList.add(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00d, 2));
        gamesList.add(new Game("[Dead Space]", 3, 2, 80.00d, 1));
        add(getCombo());
        setSize(320, 80);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JComboBox getCombo() {
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(getGames());
        return box;
    }

    private Object[] getGames() {
        return gamesList.toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure on how this would work, as my Game class is in a different file, and contains no this. markers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add toString() method to Game class. Or in getGames create a new array and populate it with names of the games.

Comment: I need to return an object, not a string, otherwise I would just return a string.

Comment: If you implement toString your combobox will display what is got from toString but you will still have the ability to get the actual object when you call getSelectedItem() etc.